# Qwt alternative

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

Is there any lib similar to Qwt but that is more flexible? Flexible in the meaning of using existing functions and parameters without need to do inheritance of basic classes like Qwt.

I would prefer Qt, but also plain c++ will be good if it can be easily implemented in Qt form.

Maybe some Qwt alternative that is still in the beginning of development, but has potential to be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an excellent alternative: QCustomPlot (http://www.qcustomplot.com/)
IMHO even better than Qwt.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this meets your needs (and whether you're still searching ;)), but maybe you'll find this interesting:
http://www.workslikeclockwork.com/index.php/components/qt-plotting-widget/
Sure has the flexibility in the sense that it's at the beginning of development (and doesn't aim to be as big as Qwt anyway). Code is relatively small and cleanly documented, so let me hear what you think.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular plot libraries:

- Qwt
- QCustomPlot
- QtCharts
- PLplot

The choice between these libraries depends on your specific goals and project requirements. If you're working on non-open-source projects and need to incorporate plots without licensing restrictions, I recommend **Qwt** (my personal preference) or **PLplot**. These libraries are available under the LGPL license, ensuring more flexibility for non-open-source projects. On the other hand, **QtCharts** and **QCustomPlot** are only accessible under the GPL license, *if you wish to maintain a cost-free solution*.